# Matching the font size in standalone with IEEEtran

Tags: fontsize, ieeetran, scaling, standalone

I have a tex file in `IEEEtran` with its default font size, which is `8pt`. I want to include an image PDF, generated by `standalone` with font size `12pt`. I set the scaling to be `scale=0.666667`, which is 2/3, to change the font size of the image to match with the main text. However, what I see at the end is that the text in the image is much smaller than `8pt`. Why?
For example, the image is generated by

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw, align=center] {This is\\12 pt\\before scaling};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and the main file is

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
This is a sample text to show the default font size
in IEEEtran document class, which is 8pt.

\includegraphics[scale=0.666667]{image.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Default fotn size of `IEEEtran` is 10pt. In `standalone` you define  12pt. Also you scale image ... on such a way is very difficult to obtain the same size of fonts.

Answer (score 4):

Note that scaling text is bad, as different font sizes might have different drawings and then do not look identical if scaled down.

Not sure if this is an option, but you can make `standalone` to use `IEEEtran` class internally which then uses the font defined there.

```
\documentclass[class={IEEEtran}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw, align=center] {This is\\the same pt\\before scaling};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Zarko , the default size of IEEEtran is `10pt`. Thus, by setting the sacling to `scale=0.83333` it matches perfectly.

Comment: why not use the default font size of standalone which is the same as your main class, at 10pt, why use 12pt and scale (which produces different fonts)